# What is the invalid keystore format error in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, expo, keystore

I just ejected my expo react native project and tried to run it using react-native run-android by I kept getting this error when running `react-native run-android`

```
`> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key androiddebugkey from store "E:\ReactNative\expoproj\movieapp\android\app\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format`
```

I tried generating the key again but it kept on giving the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you publishing or just ejecting?